# How to show AlertDialog in AsyncTask without leaking Context?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have the below code working fine to find and read a record in a Room database via an id.  Android Studio required adding a try/catch block which I've included below.

Two questions:
Can I leave the if{} section blank in onPostExecute() if there is no Exception?

How do I show an AlertDialog here without leaking contect and without using a hack via WeakReference?

```
// AsyncTask for reading an existing CardView from the database.
private static class ReadAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Quickcard> {

    private QuickcardDao asyncTaskDao;
    Exception e;

    ReadAsyncTask(QuickcardDao dao) {
        asyncTaskDao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    public Quickcard doInBackground(final Integer... params) {

        Quickcard result;
        try {
            result = asyncTaskDao.readCardForUpdate(params[0]);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.e = e;
            result = null;
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Quickcard quickcard) {

        if (e == null) {
            // *** Okay to leave this blank?  If not, what should go here?
        }
        else {
            // *** How do I show an AlertDialog here with leaking context?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use `WeakReference` to create a weak referred context. Make sure to properly check its availability. This way things get garbage collected on next GC initiation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a view object while using a thread that operates in background.. U must implement the dialog in the UI thread. When you are implementing the the asynchronous class, in that method you should show the alert dialog. Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

This is what I will do to prevent leaks from happening.

```
  private static class showDialog extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private WeakReference<MainActivity> mainActivityWeakReference;

    showDialog(MainActivity mainActivity){
        this.mainActivityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(mainActivity);

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //do your long long time consuming tasks here.
        return "Done";
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
        //Just building an alert dialog to show.
        if (mainActivityWeakReference.get() != null){
            final MainActivity activity = mainActivityWeakReference.get();
            new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Yes was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).show();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Android Studio error, says "showDialog" Constructor is never used.  Also, onPostExecute() error, says it does not override method from its superclass.  Please advise.

Comment: You will have to execute the code by:

            `new showDialog(MainActivity.this).execute();`

and for onPostExecute() error, check your braces placement.